# GroupBy DayOfWeek in Linq

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

I have this Linq query which works fine

```
var test = (from c in context.ConsumptionSet
            join pi in context.PropertiesInstanceSet on c.PropertiesInstanceID equals pi.PropertiesInstanceID
            join ep in context.EquipmentPropertiesSet on pi.EquipmentPropertiesID equals ep.EquipmentPropertiesID
            where (ep.EquipmentID == equipmentId && pi.ProprietesName == ProprietesName.Energy && c.Date <= DateTime.Today && c.Date >= EntityFunctions.AddDays(DateTime.Today, -7))
            group c by c.Date.Day into grp
            select new
            {
               test = grp.Key,
               value = (from c2 in grp select c2.Value).Max()

            }).ToList();
```

But I want to group these results by the `DayOfWeek` Property, and it seems like Linq doesn't allow it since I get this error when I replace `group c by c.Date.Day` by `group c by c.Date.DayOfWeek` :
`The specified type member 'DayOfWeek' is not supported in LINQ to Entities`

Is there any workaround to this problem ?

Comment: Use `SQL query` instead.

Comment: Hey, when posting a question on Stackoverflow can you simplify your code so it's specific please. i.e. remove all the joins and where clauses etc to make it clearer for others. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`SqlFunctions.DatePart`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/dd487171.aspx):

```
var test = (from c in context.ConsumptionSet
            join pi in context.PropertiesInstanceSet on c.PropertiesInstanceID equals pi.PropertiesInstanceID
            join ep in context.EquipmentPropertiesSet on pi.EquipmentPropertiesID equals ep.EquipmentPropertiesID
            where (ep.EquipmentID == equipmentId && pi.ProprietesName == ProprietesName.Energy && c.Date <= DateTime.Today && c.Date >= EntityFunctions.AddDays(DateTime.Today, -7))
            group c by SqlFunctions.DatePart("weekday", c.Date) into grp
            select new
            {
               test = grp.Key,
               value = (from c2 in grp select c2.Value).Max()

            }).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. And if I want to get the weekday in the my `test` property how do I do that? because I still get the integer value

Comment: You're getting `int` because `DATEPART` sql function returns `int`. Try casting it to `DayOfWeek` enumeration: `test = (DayOfWeek)grp.Key`.

Comment: Awesome, you just made my day! Thanks